# Problem in RadDataPager Localization

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, telerik

I have to use localization for Telerik RadDataPager in silverlight. For this i have developed a class inheriting RadDataPager by overriding OnApplyBaseTemplate Method. but after using this custom class now error is coming for PageSize, Source, DisplayMode etc are not found in class, Please reply if someone has done localization in RadDataPager.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using "App_GlobalResources" file and bind the text in ASP page.
you can see this URL:
[Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)